# Can I use python's np.savez to save a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, numpy

Can I use np.savez_compressed() to save a list of lists, with a variable list length? Because the length changes, I don't think it's possible to save as an array. If not, is there some sort of efficient way to save an .npz like file that contains two lists of lists. Each of the sub-lists will contain ints, tuples and arrays, with the arrays also having varying lengths.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at `pickle`?

Comment: I'm just looking at that now. I have data storage constraints (there will be 2.2 million of these files) so it may not be so straightforward.

Comment: `savez` saves the inputs to a `zip` archive, one file per input.  For individual inputs it uses `np.save`, so in the process converts the object to an array (if needed).  For embedded items, it uses `pickle`.  And the pickle method for an array is `save`.  So there's a lot of interaction between the two approaches.  I'd suggest experimenting with some small objects before diving into millions.

Comment: Thanks, will do. I was able to pickle the outputs into a .txt, but the resultant files are ~20 times larger than I need them to be!